# Javascript convert HH:MM to decimal

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function that gives me the total hours worked in a day as HH:MM. I want to convert those numbers to decimals so I can add them up. I just seem to be getting errors at the moment:

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
t = t.split(':');
return = t[0]*1 + '.' parseInt(t[1])/60;
}
```

Am I missing something important? I just keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `+` before `parseInt()`?

Comment: That would turn it into a string. I think removing the period would help.

Comment: Also why not parse both numbers as int's? Doesn't make sense to only do one.

Comment: Why add the '.'?  When you divide minutes by 60, you'll get an answer in tenths.  30/60 = .5

Comment: What are the syntax errors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
    var arr = t.split(':');
    var dec = parseInt((arr[1]/6)*10, 10);

    return parseFloat(parseInt(arr[0], 10) + '.' + (dec<10?'0':'') + dec);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC387/55/)

returns a number with two decimals at the most

```
timeToDecimal('00:01') // 0.01
timeToDecimal('00:03') // 0.05
timeToDecimal('00:30') // 0.5
timeToDecimal('10:10') // 10.16
timeToDecimal('01:30') // 1.5
timeToDecimal('3:22' ) // 3.36
timeToDecimal('22:45') // 22.75
timeToDecimal('02:00') // 2
```

Comment: This did it, thank you! I was missing a number of syntax issues :/

Comment: I'm getting incorrect values with this solution:
`
timeToDecimal("00:01") // results in 0.1
timeToDecimal("00:03") // results in 0.5
`

Comment: @PeterRoehlen - you're right, it doesn't account for leading zeros, fixed that !

Comment: @adeneo this function doesn't work for example, for 1:03, it gives 0,5 as result. I recommend Pete's solution

Comment: @adeneo - the jsfiddle you link is not the same as your solution, the jsfiddle which demonstrates your solution is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC387/304/, it gives 1.5 for 1:03, better update your solution if you've found a better one.

Answer (score 7):

Some minor syntax errors as stated above:

Remove the '=', '.' and add parseInt

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
  t = t.split(':');
  return parseInt(t[0], 10)*1 + parseInt(t[1], 10)/60;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here's a functional solution that would allow you to add more levels of accuracy: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmDsr/)

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
  return t.split(':')
          .map(function(val) { return parseInt(val, 10); } )
          .reduce( function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
              return previousValue + currentValue / Math.pow(60, index);
          });
};

console.log(timeToDecimal('2:49:50'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put an `=` after the return, and let the Math generate the decimal point for you.

This should do it

```
function timeToDecimal(t) {
    t = t.split(':');
    return parseFloat(parseInt(t[0], 10) + parseInt(t[1], 10)/60);
}  

console.log(timeToDecimal('04:30')); // 4.5
console.log(timeToDecimal('04:22')); // 4.366666666666666
console.log(timeToDecimal('12:05')); // 12.083333333333334
```

Depending on what kind of calculations you want to do, you might want to round the result of course.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLtx6/)